# TListView detecting ESC or unchanged editing

Tags: listview, subclass, c++builder, tlistview

I am trying to subclass the `WindowProc` of `TListView` to detect ESC key press after editing `TListView` caption (if user cancels editing). ListViewWndProc is getting called clearly, but the code parameter which is supposed to detect that never gets LVN_ENDLABELEDIT value. Why the commented part never gets called? I cannot see the error, it should be happening.

```cpp
TWndMethod OldWndProc;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner)
{
OldWndProc = ListView1->WindowProc;
ListView1->WindowProc = ListViewWndProc;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::ListViewWndProc(TMessage &Message)
{
if (Message.Msg == CN_NOTIFY)
    {
    LPNMHDR pnmh = reinterpret_cast<LPNMHDR>(Message.LParam);

    if (pnmh->code == LVN_ENDLABELEDIT) // UPDATE: if LVN_ENDLABELEDIT is replaced with 4294967120 it works
        {

        // !!! THE FOLLOWING NEVER HAPPENS !!!

        // UPDATE: Looks like LVN_ENDLABELEDIT is incorrectly defined in C++ Builder 2010
        // if LVN_ENDLABELEDIT is replaced with 4294967120 the code works

        LV_DISPINFO *pdi = reinterpret_cast<LV_DISPINFO*>(Message.LParam);
        if (pdi->item.pszText == NULL)
            {
            Edit1->Text = "Cancelled";
            return;
            }
        }
    }

OldWndProc(Message);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::ListView1Editing(TObject *Sender, TListItem *Item, bool &AllowEdit)
{
Edit1->Text = "Editing";
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::ListView1Edited(TObject *Sender, TListItem *Item, UnicodeString &S)
{
Edit1->Text = "Done";
}
```

Comment: I compiled this with C++ Builder Seattle and it works as it should. Which version do you use?

Comment: @KeremD I still use C++ Builder 2010, but how is that related as this is a regular WinAPI call. You haven't specified what works exactly and how you tested.

Comment: I built an app and copied your code... When I cancel editing by pressing ESC the commented part of the code is called and the Edit is filled with the text "Cancelled" . So it works as it should I think. Perhaps you should remove the C++Builder related tags if it's only about winapi?

Comment: @KeremD Can you please do `Edit1->Text = LVN_ENDLABELEDIT;` and see if it reports value `4294967190` ? That is the value defined by C++ Builder 2010, so perhaps in Seattle it is different, that is what might be the cause of this.

Comment: The shown value is `4294967120`.

Comment: @KeremD Thanks for doing that test, I've put 4294967120 and it now works in C++ Builder 2010 as expected. It looks like the case of wrong `#define` value. If you want, you can put this in answer and I will accept it, otherwise I'll answer by myself after a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, the value of `LVN_ENDLABELEDEDIT` depends on the project's [TCHAR_Mapping](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/TCHAR_Mapping), which can be changed in the Project Settings via the `"_TCHAR maps to"` configuration item.  By default, `_TCHAR` is set to `wchar_t` in C++Builder 2009 and later, unless you migrate a project from an earlier version, in which case it is `char` by default instead.

`LVN_ENDLABELEDIT` is a macro that maps to `LVN_ENDLABELEDITA` (4294967190) when `_TCHAR` is `char`, and to `LVN_ENDLABELEDITW` (4294967120) when `_TCHAR` is `wchar_t`.

Checking for both constants `LVN_ENDLABELEDEDITA` and `LVN_ENDLABELEDEDITW`, like it is done in the Delphi source code, should be OK.

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::ListViewWndProc(TMessage &Message)
{
    if (Message.Msg == CN_NOTIFY)
    {
        LPNMHDR pnmh = reinterpret_cast<LPNMHDR>(Message.LParam);

        if ((pnmh->code == LVN_ENDLABELEDITA) || (pnmh->code == LVN_ENDLABELEDITW)) 
        {
            LV_DISPINFO *pdi = reinterpret_cast<LV_DISPINFO*>(Message.LParam);
            if (pdi->item.pszText == NULL)
            {
                Edit1->Text = "Cancelled";
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    OldWndProc(Message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for added research, well done, an elegant solution!

Comment: Note that for `LVN_ENDLABELEDITA`, `pdi->item` is a `LVITEMA`, and thus `item.pszText` is a `char*`, and for `LVN_ENDLABELEDITW`, `pdi->item` is a `LVITEMW`, and thus `item.pszText` is a `wchar_t*`.  You have to watch out for that if you ever intend to use `pszText` for anything other than comparing it to NULL.

Comment: Also, note that the TCHAR mapping only affects C++, not Delphi. The VCL's source code is written in Delphi, and uses only Win32 Unicode APIs in C++Builder/Delphi 2009+, so the `TListView` should only be sending `LVN_ENDLABELEDITW` regardless of the TCHAR mapping, which explains why the code started working when `LVN_ENDLABELEDIT` was substituted with `4294967120` (`LVN_ENDLABELEDITW`).  You don't need to check for both notifications unless you plan on compiling your code for both pre-Unicode and Unicode versions of C++Builder/Delphi.

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody else gets here looking for a solution in Delphi, I have just translated Kerem D's code:

```
constructor TForm1.Create(_Owner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  OldWndProc = ListView1.WindowProc;
  ListView1.WindowProc = ListViewWndProc;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListViewWndProc(var _Message: TMessage);
var
  LvDispInfo: PLVDispInfo; // declared in CommCtrl
  Code: Integer;
begin
  if _Message.Msg = CN_NOTIFY then begin
    Code := PNMHdr(_Message.lParam).Code;
    if (Code = LVN_ENDLABELEDITA) or (Code = LVN_ENDLABELEDITW) then begin
      LvDispInfo := PLVDispInfo(_Message.lParam);
      if LvDispInfo.Item.pszText = nil then begin
        Edit1.Text := 'Cancelled';
        Exit; //==>
      end;
    end;
  end;
  OldWndProc(_Message);
end;
```

It works for me in Delphi 6 to 10.2 (used in GExperts)